# Hair not rendering properly

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hair

So I was rendering out a character in the eevee render engine when I realised something was wrong with the render. While the character looked like this in the rendered view in the viewport:[image]

When I render it out it looks like this:[image]

I am not quite sure why this happens so if anyone could tell me why it looks like this and how to fix this issue, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like insufficient particle hair render subdivisions

Comment: Are the render and viewport hair segment settings not the same number? There are both, and they are not cross-limited.